# Design - Make only one thread to run across VMs

Tags: java, multithreading

This question was asked in an interview.

There are M number of Virtual Machines (JVM). There are N number of threads running totally. N>=M.

How you ensure that across all VMs, only one thread should run. After that thread completes its task, another one thread will be given chance to run.

Comment: You could use jms queue: post one message for each concurrent processor you want and post a new message to queue whenever processor finishes task

Comment: Yes it is a broad question. As suggested, it needs a distributed lock. Since the JVMs can reside in different machine, there should be a subscription & publishing mechanism. Also the worker threads must not be blocking in nature. It needs a non blocking notification mechanism. Polling is not advised.

Comment: @jaks - that's *one* solution, with pros and cons. There are others. If I were the person asking this question in an interview, I'd be looking for you to probing a bit deeper than "distributed lock."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Summary

Essentially what you are looking for is a distributed lock. One thread at a time will be able to acquire the distributed lock and continue. Most truly distributed systems often need to coordinate with each other from time to time and there are many documented distributed locking algorithms.

## Pure Java Solutions:

You could either communicate with the other processes via socket directly, maybe using a multicast to broadcast to all listening services. Java has quite a nice socket api so this is reasonable. You could use something like RMI and have one thread act as coordinator. Or use something like a gossip protocol to coordinate as Cassandra does.

## What I would do:

Assuming you are allowed to require additional services outside of your processes. I would use Zookeeper. Zookeeper is a language agnostic Apache project designed for distributed coordination and is used heavily by many distributed systems such as Kafka.

Implementing a distributed lock in Zookeeper is described on their [wiki](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.6/recipes.html#sc_recipes_Locks)

So then all you need to do is in your N threads have them follow the recipe for acquiring the distributed lock and then only one of them will pass the coordination barrier at a time.

## Discussion:

As you may have noticed these solutions all start by assuming many threads can run unimpeded until they have coordinated and agree to take turns. If you expect to only ever have one the closest you could get would be to have a command line argument to your jar like --coordinator, only pass this to one instance and provide the IP and port of the coordinator to to all others so they can ping it and ask for permission to run. The coordinator could be as simple as just a Queue of requests to which it will respond in turn. Even if that one process spawns many threads you can classify one as the coordinator and have any that do not have the coordinator flag set wait immediately for a callback from the coordinator via any method you choose, be it sockets, message queues Zookeeper or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for one thread per JVM. Alécio's answer should already suffice. If you are asking for one thread across JVM's you will have to use some form of IPC, of which I prefer to use [Chronicle](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Chronicle), a wonderful library by Peter Lawrey. But in any case, you will not have very strict guarantee's for "one and only one application thread across all VM's"

Answer (score -1):

*In a single VM*, you can create a 'Single Thread Executor', Java provides such a thing on the **Executors** class: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29)

But you can make your own Executor if you want, for instance..make a Singleton class that receives a [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) to be executed, you can enqueue this Runnable internally which will be consumed by a 'loop' of your own, which will call the 'run()' method one after the other. Like this, you ensure that only one job is running at a time.

For a **cross-VM** solution you might have to rely on specific application server solution, maybe the [WildFly](http://www.wildfly.org/), formerly known as *JBoss*, provides such feature.

Comment: How would u insure singleton instance across jvms ?

Comment: It requires that the JVMS negotiate with each other to determine the singleton nature.

Comment: @BobDalgleish can u plz elaborate it how JVMS will interact , after this answer will be complete.

Comment: @Vipin - all the JVMs need to know about each other and one of them has to be the "master". Whether you do this dynamically, or have a shared configuration file, one JVM will be the master and carry out the thread management.

Answer (score -1):

Have each thread grab an exclusive database lock, e.g via a "select for update" query before running the task, and release the lock afterwards.